# Encrypt in Android and Decrypt in Node JS (Asymmetric Encryption)

Tags: android, node.js, cryptography, rsa

I have been trying to encrypt a string in android with private key and decrypt in node js with public key.

```
  private final static String PRIVATE_KEY = "MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDxJtyHARAMe69K0OoqoO+1yfXr\n" +
        "jfWFums8HLOjArJNyVJapUC4Dr0Rcj0e4wAy1QCQJsxCl8OeitiVAugoML39ZdCMPENc9u/LEGVU\n" +
        "lCB8B3tjB9FoDWzKEqI6CXP5Ga80dNRNakC7/aCUFdVdvYA+m4UNtbzP+KB+RrQQkA9TPBSm/25P\n" +
        "anBkCHrmRQIeC2RQz4eTjkpSpA97fmUsTjSOUrAl94OGdZ2EiWUMZuN7lF26/DUsrLlHB15l4f12\n" +
        "HfsvVyRGCkWK9pg0LLoJpCEq8IJExsrTBOT6QHT3Vx2oKFsHVp6sg2Lknk+W8ioRvLPGb6CPHu4I\n" +
        "q70bCcyVLu0lAgMBAAECggEAa3aq7YqesUFo80k4IPkI+ZTffzIKyKYzZV1Q/AKWnK1rgrODrMH8\n" +
        "pUqoTBxSmVRsZNC1U7O32+356CWceVSHReXaUrQEPOhaIb7TuSYtd7gJ1y7Dtb/NzBsTqhNOWCKG\n" +
        "/jRV642+/UdgCL3WEGkDPmMlnt9vHaqpMrylP4BDJA6Tjef9/AcJ0Df+bn+hCA0ICs1i3PXmMWaS\n" +
        "emJ/DK38caumYyuRYF/o26seU/gY0vMqwf2MH9Anb/f9RxfOtx6MlKd1SnotuYahFU0/rNSNmK/G\n" +
        "oFKPFWBX3e0nTdIz4VQtiSKScHsLkaSwSBP2kN3TK2MFRpyLylOD7C7wtM+mvQKBgQD+liJhlF5T\n" +
        "7C0zSQ2t0mGLkoL58U8eA8TZg2VXb/wl6FmTtQ3dQ+QhFIs4xgO+fCiZfjgA5RPLIvbP71vLHsYH\n" +
        "3/R+zwkQtZy4IvT5jgK4beXsIuQVtN69rwBoWvB1XDDOZlozoG/6RvNMstHeXBH11rzQSZAFzCaJ\n" +
        "u9YyIZy1HwKBgQDyfaGcaqPaso2IH/Iy7Xnu1YzsElE82KAv4tvmnzNpWWeQ8k+q8P4vwDCTR206\n" +
        "D6Vt68B6UpZH5BkiyQ1CUBMU4XJR2+JXQjMQg/T1QpK0mBLOTTZhbJa+61hoKwfgmjnYTLra4yUW\n" +
        "prq6jOxxAkQs0dCX5PrsI2L3/wbAJ5HxOwKBgQDAS+rARe9R+IzTthRs/QHNCOeBnzGhfDtOCJ+d\n" +
        "geq1P2GZ3iIQxV0lV30pbvgZA3MvLVVj56QhxdEjkqqFLENsY08sEXnJc0RjGZRsg0WuxOPsjxY1\n" +
        "Bx9Pq0XljPsfynjbDhiH8mFibAEOJ+u5x1WRmZeYxFfS6TcaxhSuXREfBQKBgQCvWmoj0nnrDHOM\n" +
        "nI1ohpJGQ+dET3qvpXcxKbwbacSjyiM6jf9OfjdSEIkP9/bkpavbcUAfNNm34xrKLNmJup4R23Xv\n" +
        "/DIRJ64Fo2bgdOPh9Jak2PEaQoxAQ7AKpBNuOBjccaAt6VRIrQkbHg1dK2Zhgth0/wD1AiHvdFxN\n" +
        "WFARQQKBgAsPKujqLWyQjpFiqk51/mbGP0xnK6QQI4981pG9UkHRugL5EIUwe4mBSa2v9nIsqJ29\n" +
        "Qk2pvaILZWUniVzcK4stbx1ML3HEcpsTi0/w49Abl0k/0ycmErey63bSgf5fszGti/MBOLVagxsa\n" +
        "7srdWq2DntK5AHy7gSk+WcMiHF8v";

private final static String PUBLIC_KEY = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8SbchwEQDHuvStDqKqDvtcn16431hbpr\n" +
        "PByzowKyTclSWqVAuA69EXI9HuMAMtUAkCbMQpfDnorYlQLoKDC9/WXQjDxDXPbvyxBlVJQgfAd7\n" +
        "YwfRaA1syhKiOglz+RmvNHTUTWpAu/2glBXVXb2APpuFDbW8z/igfka0EJAPUzwUpv9uT2pwZAh6\n" +
        "5kUCHgtkUM+Hk45KUqQPe35lLE40jlKwJfeDhnWdhIllDGbje5Rduvw1LKy5RwdeZeH9dh37L1ck\n" +
        "RgpFivaYNCy6CaQhKvCCRMbK0wTk+kB091cdqChbB1aerINi5J5PlvIqEbyzxm+gjx7uCKu9GwnM\n" +
        "lS7tJQIDAQAB";

 public String encryptedString(String plain) throws Exception {
      PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(PRIVATE_KEY, Base64.DEFAULT));
      KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
      PrivateKey key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
      byte[] dataToBytes = plain.getBytes("UTF-8");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

      return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataToBytes), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

I am encrypting with above code and trying to decrypt with below code. Its not working.

```
var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
var key = new NodeRSA();
key.importKey(privateKeyData, 'pkcs8-private');
key.importKey(publicKeyData, 'pkcs8-public');
var decrypted = key.decryptPublic(encrypted, 'utf8');
```

The process is:
I have generated a key pair and saved them statically on both sides.
Encrypting and Decrypting on Android and NodeJs individually works very well.
But its not working as i wanted, Asymmetric client-server encryption.
I also found that the two encrypted strings created by Android and NodeJs are not same.

Can anyone show me a solution or point me to an alternative for asymmetric encryption which works on Android and NodeJs.

Comment: Why you use private key for encryption? Any user with access to the public key could decrypt. Usually the assymetric encryption is performed with public key and decryption with the private. Encrypt with private key is called digital signature.

Comment: How are you sending the generated keypair from Android to node.js? Which format?

Comment: i am saving the keys in the same place as code temporarily. I plan to keep private key in Android and put public key in NodeJs. I am thinking that the decrypting procedure in node-rsa is different than android.

Comment: I am not sure if all RSA Cipher providers will use the correct block type for setup a private key for encryption. I suggest you to use a Digital Signature operation, or if you really wants to cipher, encrypt with public key and decrypt with private key

Comment: @SivaRamaKrishnaBodapti As pedrofb already said, talking about encryption in your case is wrong. What is it that you want to achieve? Be aware of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266187).

Comment: What i want is an Asymmetric Encryption between Android and NodeJs. I want to encrypt a password in Android and send it through a service to NodeJs server and decrypt it.